Astra Cerbo .m3u8 Stream: Audio Works, Video Fails in Chrome
Does anyone know why a channel in .m3u8 format generated by Astra Cerbo isn't playing when accessed from Google Chrome?
For example, I have my index.html and the local Astra server, and I'm calling the .m3u8 file generated by Astra. However, when I open index.html in the browser, only the audio plays but the video does not. (The most unusual thing is that both video and audio work fine in VLC with the same URL.) Attached are the evidences.

simple html:
<html lang="es">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Reproductor de Video</title>
 <!-- Incluir estilos de Clappr -->
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clappr@latest/dist/clappr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="player" class="video-container"></div>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clappr@latest/dist/clappr.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    var player = new Clappr.Player({
     source: "http://195.26.245.177:8001/play/a00d/index.m3u8",
     parentId: "#player",
     width: "640px",
     height: "360px",
     autoPlay: true,
     mimeType: "application/x-mpegURL"
    });
   </script>
  </body>
</html>

